# Sorting collection via nested relationships

Tags: php, laravel, collections

Ok so I have an app that searches through course applications which each belong to an applicant. When I search the applications for a course title it returns the required result set but I would like to sort it by the applicant's date of birth.

How can I do this? I've tried sorting the collection doing $applications->sortBy('applicant.dob') but this seems to just order it by each applicant not the overall collection.

#### Edit

Here's all of my code... http://laravel.io/bin/PD81z

Any one have an idea how I can approach this?

Thanks!

Comment: You need join, you can't sort main query by related query otherwise.

Answer (score -1):

OK

Your table course and table applicant are actually many-to-many relationship

For this to work, table course_applitions serves as a proxy to link the two table.

see the post, especially the part about many-to-many relationships

http://scotch.io/tutorials/php/a-guide-to-using-eloquent-orm-in-laravel

When fetching results from related tables using the above way, you can always add sort options.

Cheers!

Comment: Ah I think I haven't explained myself clearly, there is no courses table just an applicant and application table. A one-to-many relationship. I've also updated my code as I had (very foolishly) missed out my sorting method

Comment: OK. then it's very easy(I have not tested in local environment)